# Problema al intentar subir múltiples imágenes desde Angular a Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Estoy intentando subir múltiples imágenes asociadas a una clase Usuario a mi base de datos local, en mi `Front` estoy utilizando `Angular` y en mi `Backend` `Spring Boot`. La idea es la siguiente tener una clase Usuario que contenga un conjunto de datos como nombre, apellido y un arreglo de fotos, le he dado muchas vueltas al asunto y no logro completar mi objetivo.

***UsuarioDTO.java***

```
    @Entity
    @Table (name ="usuario")
    public class UsuarioDTO {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @Column
    private String apellido;
    @Column
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Fotos.class)
    private List<Fotos> foto;
```

***Fotos.java***

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "fotos")
    public class Fotos {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "picByte", length = 1000)
    private byte[] picByte;
```

***Controller***

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public BodyBuilder uplaodImage(@RequestBody UsuarioDTO usr){
        
        // Aqui me están llegando las fotos en un arreglo como se muestran en la imagen adjunta y me tira error ` at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 47] (through reference chain: com.api.Test.UsuarioDTO["foto"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])]`
    }
```

En mi ***FRONTEND*** utilizo lo siguiente:

***usuario.html***

```
    <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
     id="selectButton" (click)="fileInput.click()">Seleccionar Imagen</button>
                        <input type="file" (change)="onselect($event)" hidden 
      multiple #fileInput accept="image/*" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

***usuario.component***

```
    onselect(e) {
      if (e.target.files) {
      var filesAmount = e.target.files.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i]);
      reader.onload = (events: any) => {
        this.usuario.fotos.push(events.target.result);
      };
    }
  }
}


    Agregar(usuario: Usuario){
       this.service.createUsuario(usuario).subscribe(data=>{
       this.snackBar.open('Usuario Agregado con Exito', 'Cerrar', {duration: 
   3000}); 
})
```

***Usuario***

```
    export class Usuario{
    id: number
    nombre: string;
    apellido: string;
    fotos: any [] ;
}
```

***Usuario.service***

```
    createUsuario(usr: Usuario){ 
    return this.http.post<Usuario>(+'/upload', usr);
  }
```

Desde mi ***FRONTEND*** el arreglo de imágenes lo estoy enviando de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No concuerda lo que subes (un array de Strings que representan a las fotos en Base64) con lo que esperas en el controlador de Spring (un array de objetos Foto).

Comment: @PabloLozano Cuales serían los cambios que debería realizar para subir un arreglo de un objeto y que lo tome mi Spring (perdón soy muy novato en el tema).

Comment: Personalmente preferiría usar un FormData para enviar las fotos en formato binario, ya que así ocupan un tercio menos que en Base64. Aquí tienes un buen ejemplo: https://amoelcodigo.com/angular-spring-boot-archivos/

Comment: @PabloLozano como te comente soy novato y se me complica aplicar el código que muestra el ejemplo dado que allí solo se ocupa de subir imágenes de tipo `MultipartFiles` pero no esta asociado a ninguna otra clase, se me complica entender como armar el el método `POST` cuando tengo q pasarle datos por un lado que serían los datos del usuario y las imágenes por el otro.